# Is this function strongly convex? or could I find a value space to make this function strongly convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

I want to judge if this function $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=(\frac{x_1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}})^2+(\frac{x_2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}})^2+...+(\frac{x_n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}})^2$ strongly convex for each $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$? Well, I don't know how to prove or disprove it. If $f(x)$ is not strongly convex on $\mathbb{R}$, does it possible that it is strongly convex on specific value space or interval according to the value of $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer

First, note $f$ is constant on the line $L_i=\{\lambda e_i:\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\}$ for all $i$ (where $e_i$ is the $i$-th vector of the canonical base of $\mathbb{R}^n$), so it can't be strongly convex.

Second, given $z\in\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ s.t. $\sum z_i\neq 0$, define the function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ as $g(s)=f(s,z)$. This function is concave when $s\geq \frac{2\sum z_i^2}{\sum z_i}$. Indeed, 
$$
g'(s)=\frac{2}{(s+\sum z_i)^3}\left(s\sum z_i -\sum z_i^2\right)
$$
while
$$
g''(s)=\frac{4}{(s+\sum z_i)^4}\left(2\sum z_i^2 -s\sum z_i\right)
$$
so $f$ can't be strongly convex on sets of the form $\Omega=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:$ there is $i\in\{1,...,n\}$ s.t. $x_i\geq \frac{\sum_{j\neq i}x_j^2}{\sum_{j\neq i}x_j}\}$

However, if there is $t<1$ s.t. $s\leq \frac{2t\sum z_i^2}{\sum z_i}$ we can show there is some $m>0$ s.t. 
\begin{eqnarray}
g''(s) & = & \frac{4}{(s+\sum z_i)^4}\left(2\sum z_i^2 -s\sum z_i\right)\\
& \geq & \frac{4}{\left(\frac{2t\sum z_i^2}{\sum z_i}+\sum z_i\right)^4}\left(2(1-t)\sum z_i^2 \right)\\
& \geq & m
\end{eqnarray}
which shows the function $f$ is strongly convex on intervals $[a,b]$ where $$
a=(x_1,...,x_{i-1},c,x_{i+1},...,x_n)
$$ 
and 
$$
b=(x_1,...,x_{i-1},d,x_{i+1},...,x_n)
$$
when $c<d\leq \frac{2t\sum_{j\neq i} x_j^2}{\sum_{j\neq i} x_j}$ for some $t<1$.

Third, $f$ is strongly convex on intervals $[a,b]$ where $a=e_i$, $b=e_j$. Indeed, if $c=se_i+(1-s)e_j$ and $d=te_i+(1-t)e_j%$ then 
$$
\nabla f(c)=(6s-4s^2-2)e_i+(2s-4s^2)e_j
$$
(and similarly for $\nabla f(d)$) so we can show
$$
\langle\nabla f(c)- \nabla f(d),c-d\rangle=4(s-t)^2=2\cdot (2(s-t)^2)=2\Vert c-d\Vert_2^2
$$

Comment: Thank you for answering. Actually, I can specify $\forall x_i \in [p,q]$ and $p>0$. so if I add a condition that $q \leq 2p$, does it means the second derivative of $g(s)$ is always larger than 0? Then I can conclude that $f(X)$ is strongly convex. By the way, is there some theorem for your last equation $<\Delta f(c)-\Delta f(d),c-d>=2{\left\|c-d\right\|}_{2}^{2}$ satisfied that the $f(x)$ strongly convex hold?

Comment: About your first question, I don't think so. For instance, if $p>\frac{2\sum_{j\neq i} x_j^2}{\sum_{j\neq i} x_j}$ then, from what we showed, we deduce the second derivative of $g$ will be negative on $[p,q]$. In other words. The sign of $g''(s)$ on $[p,q]$ depends not on the relationship between $p$ and $q$, but rather, in the relationship between $q$ and $\frac{2\sum_{j\neq i} x_j^2}{\sum_{j\neq i} x_j}$

Comment: About your second question. Sorry, I assumed you were familiar with this characterization: *$f$ is strongly convex in $\Omega$ if and only if there is some $m>0$ s.t. for all $c,d\in\Omega$, $\langle \nabla f(c)-\nabla f(d),c-d\rangle \geq m\Vert c-d\Vert_2^2$*. Sadly I didn't find any reference where this is explicitly proved.

Comment: (continued) Then again, if you are familiar with the definition *$f$ is strongly convex if there is some $m$ s.t. $g(x)=f(x)-\frac{m}{2}\Vert x\Vert_2^2$ is convex*, you can deduce the characterization applying the first order characterization of convexity to the function $g$.

Comment: Yeah, for the first question, I mean for all the $x_i$, they satisfy $x_i \in [p,q]$ and $p>0$. So the $\frac{2\sum_{j \neq i} {x_j}^2}{\sum_{j \neq i} {x_j}}$, it's  a monofonically increasing function on the interval $[p,q]$. So its minimum is when all the $x_j = p, {j \neq i}$, that is $2p$. Thus if $2p>q$, the condition will always be satisfied. Am I right? For the second question, I get what you mean, thanks!

Comment: Indeed, you are correct.